# export and import all the permissions on schema objects within a database SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

Is it possible to export all the users roles and their permissions on schema objects within a database in a .sql file and import them later in an other database ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of answers to a similar question that might be of use to you.

[How to export all the security-related information from a SQL Server database](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/58772/how-to-export-all-the-security-related-information-from-a-sql-server-database)

The answer I believe is yes. You can use SSMS to generate scripts and have it filtered to just users.

Here is a webpage detailing how you would [Create Script to Copy Database Schema and All The Objects](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/05/07/sql-server-2008-2008-r2-create-script-to-copy-database-schema-and-all-the-objects-data-schema-stored-procedure-functions-triggers-tables-views-constraints-and-all-other-database-objects/).